# Angular 8 FormControl disable not being sent to child component

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following custom input in my code:

```html
<nivel-servico-slider formControlName="fornecedor_a"></nivel-servico-slider>
```

which has all properties for a custom input as described in Angular's guide to [creating a custom input](https://v8.material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control), however when I set that FormControl to disabled:

```js
this.form.get('fornecedor_a').disable();
```

the disabled attribute is not set to the custom component (`<nivel-servico-slider>`), which doesn't trigger the get/setter for disabled inside the component:

```js
@Input()
get disabled(): boolean {
  return this.internalDisabled;
}
set disabled(value: boolean) {
  console.log(value);
  this.internalDisabled = coerceBooleanProperty(value);
  if (this.internalDisabled) {
    this.input.disable();
  } else {
    this.input.enable();
  };
  this.stateChanges.next();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you do ```this.form.get('fornecedor_a').disabled = true```, the setter will get triggered?

Comment: @TwoHorses `Cannot assign to 'disabled' because it is a read-only property.`

Comment: Just for debugging try ```(this.form.get('fornecedor_a').disabled as any) = true```

Comment: @TwoHorses Almost the same error: `Cannot set property disabled of [object Object] which has only a getter`. Note: the FormControl does have disabled as true with `.disable()`, its just not sending it to the child component.

Comment: Can you provide a codesandbox or a more complete version of your custom component class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using formControlName on your custom component, there is most likely a custom value accessor implemented https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor

so, to catch "disabling", you should implement `setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean)?: void`